# How perform filter between 2 array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop

I have 2 arrays  as follows,

```
 var arr1 = [{'_id':'192983','nt':'1246699993'},{'_id':'192984','nt':'1246699994'}]; 

 var arr2 = [{'title':'ABX1','nt':'2398389'},{'title':'ABX2','nt':'1246699994'}];
```

Result expected:

```
[{'title':'ABX2','nt':'1246699994'}]
```

From the 2 arrays, I want to exclude the one which matches the 'nt' key in both the arrays,

I tried like below,

```
for (var i =0;i< arr1.length;i++) {

      for (var j = 0;j < arr2.length;j++) {
             if (arr1[i].nt !== arr2[j].nt) {
                   finalArr.push(arr2[j]);
              }
      }
}
```

But this loop taking n power 2 times. Can anyone please suggest me the easiest method of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: which result do you get? is that the wanted? please add the wanted result.

Comment: *"I want to exclude the the one whih mathes the 'nt' olum"* Is the `c` key broken on your keyboard?

Comment: @Nina Sholz,added the expeted result.

Comment: @Robby,yes unfortunately :(.

Answer (score 0):

```js
     var arr1 = [{'_id':'192983','nt':'1246699993'},{'_id':'192984','nt':'1246699994'}]; 

     var arr2 = [{'title':'ABX1','nt':'2398389'},{'title':'ABX2','nt':'1246699994'}]; 

    let answer = [];

    arr2.forEach(x => {
      if(!arr1.some(y => y['nt'] === x['nt'])){
        answer.push(x)
      }
    })

    console.log(answer)
```

The above answer is based on what you written. You wish to find the similar item, and exclude it, meaning not included hence the result should be `{'title':'ABX1','nt':'2398389'}`

But based on your expected result you want `{'title':'ABX2','nt':'1246699994'}` instead.

Either way, go thru my solution and inside the if condition remove the `!` to get your "expected" output

Alternatively, instead of using forEach, you can use `filter` method as below

```js
let answer = arr2.filter(x=> {
     return arr1.some(y=>y['nt']===x['nt']);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the inefficiency, compare the two approaches below:

Inefficient (maximum i*j iterations):

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 'd', 'e'];

for (var i in list1) {
    for (var j in list2) {
        if (list1[i] == list2[j]) {
            alert('found ' + list1[i] + ' in both lists');
        }
    }
}
```

Efficient (maximum i+j iterations)

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 'd', 'e'];
var lookup = {};

for (var j in list2) {
    lookup[list2[j]] = list2[j];
}

for (var i in list1) {
    if (typeof lookup[list1[i]] != 'undefined') {
        alert('found ' + list1[i] + ' in both lists');
        break;
    } 
}
```

Once you're using a dictionary lookup instead of looping over both arrays, you just need to implement your logic for matching the relevant keys and outputting them to a results array.

Comment: Avoid `For...In` at all cost for the above scenario :p

Comment: I'm sure it can be optimised, but I was highlighting the difference between the O(N2) complexity of Testimg198's version and the O(N) complexity of my second example. This appears to be the main part of their question.